# Select rows within a particular time range

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like:

```
TimeStamp                    Category

2013-11-02 07:57:18 AM         0
2013-11-02 08:07:19 AM         0
2013-11-02 08:07:21 AM         0
2013-11-02 08:07:25 AM         1
2013-11-02 08:07:29 AM         0
2013-11-02 08:08:18 AM         0
2013-11-02 08:09:20 AM         0
2013-11-02 09:04:18 AM         0
2013-11-02 09:05:22 AM         0
2013-11-02 09:07:18 AM         0
```

What I want to do is to select the +-10 minute time frames when `Category` is "1".

For this case, because `category = 1` is at `2013-11-02 08:07:25 AM`, I want to select all rows within `07:57:25 AM to  08:17:25 AM`.

What is the best way to handle this task?

addition, there maybe multiple "1" for each time frame. (the real data frame is more complicate, it contains multiple TimeStamp with different users, i.e. there is another column named "UserID")

Comment: Now all is left to do is some epic benchamrk on all the answers I guess.

Comment: @DavidArenburg - I know where my answer will fall on that ;-) I'm relying on computing power increasing exponentially, or people needing to grab a coffee every couple of hours while their code runs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In base R, without lubridate-ing or anything else (assuming that you're going to convert TimeStamp to a `POSIXct` object), like:

```
df$TimeStamp <- as.POSIXct(TimeStamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
df[with(df, abs(difftime(TimeStamp[Category==1],TimeStamp,units="mins")) <= 10 ),]

#            TimeStamp Category
#2 2013-11-02 08:07:19        0
#3 2013-11-02 08:07:21        0
#4 2013-11-02 08:07:25        1
#5 2013-11-02 08:07:29        0
#6 2013-11-02 08:08:18        0
#7 2013-11-02 08:09:20        0
```

If you've got multiple `1`'s, you'd have to loop over it like:

```
check <- with(df, 
  lapply(TimeStamp[Category==1], function(x) abs(difftime(x,TimeStamp,units="mins")) <= 10 ) 
)
df[do.call(pmax, check)==1,]
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I would approach this using `data.table::foverlaps`

First, convert `TimeStamp` to a proper `POSIXct`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, TimeStamp := as.POSIXct(TimeStamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")]
```

Then we will create a temporary data set where `Category == 1` to join against. We will also create an "end" column and `key` by both "start" and "end" columns

```
df2 <- setkey(df[Category == 1L][, TimeStamp2 := TimeStamp], TimeStamp, TimeStamp2)
```

Then, we will do the same for `df` but will set 10 minutes intervals

```
setkey(df[, `:=`(start = TimeStamp - 600, end = TimeStamp + 600)], start, end)
```

Then, all is left to do is to run `foverlaps` and subset by matched incidences

```
indx <- foverlaps(df, df2, which = TRUE, nomatch = 0L)$xid
df[indx, .(TimeStamp,  Category)]
#              TimeStamp Category
# 1: 2013-11-02 08:07:19        0
# 2: 2013-11-02 08:07:21        0
# 3: 2013-11-02 08:07:25        1
# 4: 2013-11-02 08:07:29        0
# 5: 2013-11-02 08:08:18        0
# 6: 2013-11-02 08:09:20        0
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work:

Data:

As per @DavidArenburg 's comment (and as mentioned in his answer) the right way to convert the timestamp column into a `POSIXct` object is (if it not already):

```
df$TimeStamp <- as.POSIXct(df$TimeStamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p")
```

Solution:

```
library(lubridate) #for minutes
library(dplyr)     #for between
pickrows <- function(df) {
  #pick category == 1 rows
  df2 <- df[df$Category==1,]
  #for each timestamp create two variables start and end
  #for +10 and -10 minutes
  #then pick rows between them
  lapply(df2$TimeStamp, function(time) {
      start <- time - minutes(10)
      end   <- time + minutes(10)
      df[between(df$TimeStamp, start, end),]
  })
} 

#run function
pickrows(df)
```

Output:

```
> pickrows(df)
[[1]]
            TimeStamp Category
2 2013-11-02 08:07:19        0
3 2013-11-02 08:07:21        0
4 2013-11-02 08:07:25        1
5 2013-11-02 08:07:29        0
6 2013-11-02 08:08:18        0
7 2013-11-02 08:09:20        0
```

Keep in mind that the output in case of multiple `Category==1` rows, my function's output will be a list (in this ocassion it only has one element) so a `do.call(rbind, pickrows(df))` will be needed to combine everything in one data.frame.

Comment: Hi @DavidArenburg. Yeah in my R session I have but since his timestamp column has the exact default `POSIXct` format I assume it is like that on his data.frame. In our case we read it as text. This is why `dput` is better.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yeah this was on my script when I constructed my answer and it works: `df$TimeStamp <- as.POSIXct(df$TimeStamp)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I will make the assumption that his timestamp is correct and there will be no PM later on (for am times). You are adding a data cleaning process in your answer which is fine but it is not necessary. There is no evidence that his time format goes wrong later on..

Comment: @DavidArenburg I stand corrected. You are absolutely right Dave. I didn't know the difference here. Thanks a lot. This was a very good lesson for me here. I will include in my answer and give credit.

Answer (score 4):

Using lubridate:

```
df$TimeStamp <- ymd_hms(df$TimeStamp)
span10 <- (df$TimeStamp[df$Category == 1] - minutes(10)) %--% (df$TimeStamp[df$Category == 1] + minutes(10))
df[df$TimeStamp %within% span10,]
            TimeStamp Category
2 2013-11-02 08:07:19        0
3 2013-11-02 08:07:21        0
4 2013-11-02 08:07:25        1
5 2013-11-02 08:07:29        0
6 2013-11-02 08:08:18        0
7 2013-11-02 08:09:20        0
```

Comment: I really like your solution! Thank you for posting I didn't even know about %--%.

Answer (score 3):

I personally like the simplicity in the base R answer from @thelatemail. But just for fun, I'll provide another answer using *rolling joins* in `data.table`, as opposed to *overlapping range joins* solution provided by @DavidArenburg.

```
require(data.table)
dt_1 = dt[Category == 1L]
setkey(dt, TimeStamp)

ix1 = dt[.(dt_1$TimeStamp - 600L), roll=-Inf, which=TRUE] # NOCB
ix2 = dt[.(dt_1$TimeStamp + 600L), roll= Inf, which=TRUE] # LOCF

indices = data.table:::vecseq(ix1, ix2-ix1+1L, NULL) # not exported function
dt[indices]
#              TimeStamp Category
# 1: 2013-11-02 08:07:19        0
# 2: 2013-11-02 08:07:21        0
# 3: 2013-11-02 08:07:25        1
# 4: 2013-11-02 08:07:29        0
# 5: 2013-11-02 08:08:18        0
# 6: 2013-11-02 08:09:20        0
```

This should work just fine even if you've got more than one cell where `Category` is 1, AFAICT. It'd be great to wrap this up as a feature for this type of operations for `data.table`...

PS: refer to the other posts for converting `TimeStamp` into POSIXct format.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with `dplyr` and `lubridate`. Here are the steps:

Find where `category ==1`, add to this, `+` and `-` 10 minutes with the `lubridate`'s `minutes` with a simple `c(-1, 1) * minutes(10)` **then** using `filter` to subset based on the two interval stored in the `rang` vector.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
wi1 <- which(dat$Category == 1 )
rang <- dat$TimeStamp[wi1] +  c(-1,1) * minutes(10)
dat %>% filter(TimeStamp >= rang[1] & TimeStamp <= rang[2])
            TimeStamp Category
1 2013-11-02 08:07:19        0
2 2013-11-02 08:07:21        0
3 2013-11-02 08:07:25        1
4 2013-11-02 08:07:29        0
5 2013-11-02 08:08:18        0
6 2013-11-02 08:09:20        0
```