# Select data range from timestamp based on row.names

Tags: r, timestamp

If I have a data frame and I wish to select a training set based on time range

```
df <- data.frame(timestamp = seq(as.POSIXct('2013-08-02 12:00:00'),
                                as.POSIXct('2013-08-06 05:00:00'), len =(45), 
                   x = sample(1:100, 45), y = sample(200:500, 45)))
```

I will now convert the timestamp into row.names

```
row.names(df) = df$timestamp
```

Since I have indexed the row.names I should be able to select a range for a training set:

```
 # Select the range 
 s = '2013-08-02 12:00:00'
 e = '2013-08-03 10:15:00'

 # Select the training dataset 

 training = df[s:e,]
```

But when I run the above code I get the following error:

```
 #Error in s:e : NA/NaN argument
 #In addition: Warning messages:
 #1: In `[.data.frame`(df, s:e, ) : NAs introduced by coercion
 #2: In `[.data.frame`(df, s:e, ) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong here!

I know that ts or some other package will solve the issue, but isn't there any base R functions I can use.

The answers I reviewed before posting my question.

[Select rows within a particular time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038050/select-rows-within-a-particular-time-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` will not give you range of rows to be selected. You need to find out the respective index and then create a sequence between them and then subset

```
df[which(row.names(df) == s) : which(row.names(df) == e), , drop = FALSE]

#                              timestamp
#2013-08-02 12:00:00 2013-08-02 12:00:00
#2013-08-02 14:01:21 2013-08-02 14:01:21
#2013-08-02 16:02:43 2013-08-02 16:02:43
#2013-08-02 18:04:05 2013-08-02 18:04:05
#2013-08-02 20:05:27 2013-08-02 20:05:27
#2013-08-02 22:06:49 2013-08-02 22:06:49
#2013-08-03 00:08:10 2013-08-03 00:08:10
#2013-08-03 02:09:32 2013-08-03 02:09:32
#2013-08-03 04:10:54 2013-08-03 04:10:54
#2013-08-03 06:12:16 2013-08-03 06:12:16
#2013-08-03 08:13:38 2013-08-03 08:13:38
#2013-08-03 10:15:00 2013-08-03 10:15:00
```

If there is a possibility of multiple values of `s` and `e` it is better to use `which.max` in such cases since `which.max` returns index of first maximum.

Moreover, you don't need convert to `rownames` at all. You can achieve the same with `timestamp` column itself.

```
df[which.max(df$timestamp == s) : which.max(df$timestamp == e), , drop = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple indexing instruction.

```
inx <- as.POSIXct(s) <= row.names(df) & row.names(df) <= as.POSIXct(e)
df[inx, ]
```

I have left it like this for clarity, you can make it a one-liner.